# Code is working properly but if data is empty that time validation is not working

Tags: cakephp

i have made a code generated random number and save all number in database(that part of code is working) but i have problem in validation without enter any no on view page redirect this url admin_manage_epin.ctp, validation not working

admin_create_epin.ctp(view)

```
<tr>
Add E-pin:(No of E-Pin)
<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('e_pin',array('label'=>false));?></td> 
</tr>
```

epins_controllers.php(controller)

```
public function admin_create_epin(){
 if(!empty($this->data)){
   $limit = $this->data['Epin']['e_pin'];

   for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)
     {
     $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,11)."<br/>";
     $this->data['Epin']['e_pin'] = $random;
     $this->Epin->id =null;
     $this->Epin->save($this->data); 
   }   

      $this->Session->setFlash("Epin has been added");
      $this->Redirect(array('action'=>'admin_manage_epin')); 
   }
 }
```

epin.php(model)

```
<?php class Epin extends appModel{
var $name ="Epin";
var $validate = array(
                      'e_pin'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                        'message'=>'Please type No of epin'
                      ));
  }
 ?>
```

i think i have problem in my controller function admin_create_epin

thanks

Comment: If the data is empty, there is nothing *to* validate. Intended behaviour.

Comment: but i want to take validation if data is empty validation should be fired

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check if the actual field is empty - since submitting a form will still have an array:

```
if(!empty($this->data['Epin']['e_pin'])) {
```

Within your `for()` loop, you should be using `create()` and don't set `id`:

```
for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++) {
    $this->Epin->create();
    $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,11)."<br/>";
    $this->data['Epin']['e_pin'] = $random;
    //...
```

Your `redirect` should be lowercase:

```
$this->redirect(...
```

It's quite difficult to understand what you're actually asking, but if you're trying to redirect if the form was submitted empty, the redirect should be one more level out:

```
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash("Epin has been added");
    $this->Redirect(array('action'=>'admin_manage_epin')); 
}
```

Comment: thanks @Dave for reply, i used it if(!empty($this->data['Epin']['e_pin'])) {
 after that url not redirect due to empty array but validation not fired

Comment: How do you know data validation isn't "being fired" if you're redirecting?  Can you try to explain your specific problem again?